# How to pull json data from data mysql as object using laravel5?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

I have a table which contain JSON in a column that I have to get as an object 
but when I pull data using laravel model then it obviously return as JSON or string which I have to decode every where, where I use this model (this is not dry concept) but the thing is if I pull one record and one place then it is only one execution of code and ok but what if I have to pull collection of the data and multiple place then I have to run same decode every time is there any way in laravel that can do for me instead of using self made loop

**here is the table**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   table                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id | title | text                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 |   A1  | {"subject":"Subject1","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 2 |   A2  | {"subject":"Subject2","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 3 |   A3  | {"subject":"Subject3","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 4 |   A4  | {"subject":"Subject4","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 5 |   A5  | {"subject":"Subject5","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 6 |   A6  | {"subject":"Subject6","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 7 |   A7  | {"subject":"Subject7","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 8 |   A8  | {"subject":"Subject8","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 9 |   A9  | {"subject":"Subject9","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..."} |
| 10|  A10  | {"subject":"Subject10","word":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."}  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**i have tried this**

```
$tables = TableModel::all();
foreach ($tables as &$table) {
    $table->text = json_decode($table->text);
}
```

**Result what I want**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => A1
            [text] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [subject] => Subject1
                    [word] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => A2
            [text] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [subject] => Subject2
                    [word] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                )

        )

    ...
)
```

If is there any easy way to that which is more efficient and follow dry 
then share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i called model then loop through it and overwrite then element with object using `json_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Attribute Casting` concept to get the result in the desired format every time you fetch the record from database. To convert from JSON to Array you can use the following code.

```
protected $casts = [
    'text' => 'array',
];
```

As mention in the [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Comment: Thanks :)   this helps me lot and saved the day